# How to install mcrypt php 7.2.3 extension in xampp for windows?

Tags: php, windows, laravel, xampp, mcrypt

My PHP Version 7.2.3 and xampp pack do not have the mcrypt extension. 
It is not mentioned in the phpinfo() neither in the php.ini file in order to enable it.

I have downloaded mcrypt from this link:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/
but I don't know how to integrate it as php extension.
I need solution for xampp in windows please

Comment: Um, that's going to be a challenge consider they removed it in 7.2.   http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php

Answer (score 6):

You don't

See http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php

> This feature was **DEPRECATED** in PHP **7.1.0**, and **REMOVED** in PHP **7.2.0**.
>
> Alternatives to this feature include:
>
> - Sodium (available as of PHP 7.2.0)
> - OpenSSL

They didn't include this one

- PHPSecLib

But it's a third party library so I can't say I blame them, I've used it for some time and never heard anything bad about it yet.

Answer (score -1):

Change PHP version to lower version, like "7.0.33" or below.
than it will help to achieve the code goal

Comment: he is right I just shift from 7.2 to 5.6 its working fine now